# Do generators belong to the Lie group or the Lie algebra?

Tags: terminology, group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

In Physics papers, would it be correct to say that when there is mention of generators, they really mean the generators of the Lie algebra rather than generators of the Lie group? For example I've seen sources that say that the $SU(N)$ *group* has $N^2-1$ generators, but actually these are generators for the Lie algebra aren't they?

Is this also true for representations? When we say a field is in the adjoint rep, does this typically mean the adjoint rep of the algebra rather than of the gauge group?

Comment: I gave another answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/8662

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/563709/226902

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a basis for the Lie algebra, you can talk of these basis vectors as being "generators for the Lie group".  This is true in the sense that, by using the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map) on linear combinations of them, you generate (at least locally) a copy of the Lie group.  So they're sort of "primitive infinitesimal elements" that you can use to build the local structure of the Lie group from.

Re your second point, yes, fields in gauge theories are generally Lie algebra-valued entities.

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy response to my question. So I guess that, in the strictest sense, the Pauli matrices aren't generators of the SU(2) group (they don't combine via the group action to generate the group). However, as you say, the SU(2) group can be obtained from them via the exponential of their linear combinations - so we call them generators. Technically, they are the generators of su(2) (the Lie algebra). Do you think this is a good way to view it?

Comment: I guess they "generate" the Lie algebra in the sense that any basis "generates" the vector space it spans.  You're right that they don't combine *via* the group action to generate the group, they combine *via* the exponential map to generate it.

Comment: Well to be pedantic, even the exponentials of a random basis of the LA don't necessarily generate the group in the group-theoretic sense: e.g. take $G = S^1$ with $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb R, exp(x) =e^{ix}$, then $x=\pi$ is a basis of $\mathbb R$ (like any $0 \neq x\in \mathbb R$), but $exp(\pi) =-1$ just generates the two-element subgroup $\pm 1$. What is true is that for any such basis element $x$, $\exp(\mathbb Rx)$ is a "one-parameter"-subgroup of $G$, and all those together would generate the connected component of $G$ (in the above example, $S^1$ already $=exp(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 17):

User twistor59 has addressed the part regarding the "generator" terminology, but let me give a bit more detail on the second part of the question.  I'm going to restrict the discussion to matrix Lie groups for simplicity.

**Some background.**

Given a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, there exist two mappings $\mathrm{Ad}$ and $\mathrm{ad}$, both are called "adjoint."  In particular for all $g\in G$ and for all $X,Y\in\mathfrak g$, we define $\mathrm {Ad}_g:\mathfrak g\to \mathfrak g$ and $\mathrm{ad}_X$ by
$$
  \mathrm{Ad}_g(X) = gX g^{-1}, \qquad \mathrm{ad}_X(Y) = [X,Y]
$$
The mapping $\mathrm{Ad}$ which takes an element $g\in G$ and maps it to $\mathrm{Ad}_g$ is a representation of $G$ acting on $\mathfrak g$, while the mapping $\mathrm{ad}$ which takes an element $X\in \mathfrak g$ and maps it to $\mathrm{ad}_X$ is a representation of $\mathfrak g$ acting on itself.

In other words, $\mathrm{Ad}$ is a Lie group representation while $\mathrm{ad}$ is a Lie algebra representation, but they both act on the Lie algebra which is a vector space.

**Aside.**

In response to user Christoph's comment below.  Note that if we define the conjugation operation $\mathrm{conj}$ by
$$
  \mathrm{conj}_g(h) = g h g^{-1}
$$
Then for matrix Lie groups (which I initially stated I was restricting the discussion to for simplicity) we have
$$
  \frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}\mathrm{conj}_g(e^{tX}) =\mathrm{Ad}_g X
$$

**Addressing the question.**

Having said all of this, in my experience (in high energy theory), physicists usually are referring to $\mathrm{ad}$, the Lie algebra representation.  In fact, you'll often see it written in physics texts that

> generators $T_a$ of the Lie algebra furnish the adjoint representation provided $(T_a)_b^{\phantom bc} = f_{ab}^{\phantom{ab}c}$.

where the $f$'s are the structure constants of the Lie algebra with respect to the basis $T_a$;
$$
  [T_a,T_b] = f_{ab}^{\phantom{ab}c} T_c
$$
But notice that
$$
  \mathrm{ad}_{T_a}(T_b) = [T_a,T_b] = f_{ab}^{\phantom{ab}c} T_c
$$
which shows that the matrix representations of the generators in the Lie algebra representation $\mathrm{ad}$ precisely have entries given by the structure constants.

**Addendum (May 22, 2013).**

Let a Lie-algebra valued field $\phi$ on a manifold $M$ be given.  If the field transforms under the representation $\mathrm{Ad}$ (which is a representation of the *group* acting on the algebra) then we have
$$
  \phi(x)\to \mathrm{Ad}_g(\phi(x)) = g\phi(x) g^{-1}
$$
But recall that ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma)) $\mathrm{Ad}$ is related to $\mathrm{ad}$ (a representation on the *algebra* acting on itself) as follows: Write an element of the Lie group as $g=e^X$ for some $X$ in the algebra (here we assume that $G$ is connected) then
$$
  \mathrm{Ad}_g(\phi(x)) = e^{\mathrm{ad}_X}\phi(x) = \phi(x) + \mathrm{ad}_X(\phi(x)) +\mathcal O(X^2)
$$
so that the corresponding "infinitesimal" transformation law is
$$
  \delta\phi(x) = \mathrm{ad}_X(\phi(x))
$$
So when talking about a field transforming under the adjoint representation, $\mathrm{Ad}$ and $\mathrm{ad}$ in some sense have the same content; $\mathrm{ad}$ is the "infinitesimal" version of $\mathrm {Ad}$

Comment: shouldn't $\mathrm{Ad}$ be the differential of conjugation instead of conjugation itself, ie $\mathrm{Ad}_g=\mathrm{T}_e(\mathrm{conj}_g):\mathrm{T}_eG\to \mathrm{T}_eG$, whereas $\mathrm{conj}_g:G\to G$?

Comment: @Christoph Note that I prefaced the discussion by restricting to matrix Lie groups.  In this case, the definition I made makes sense (although perhaps it is non-standard).  See the **Aside** section.  Regarding naming conventions for Ad v. conj, I am following the convention of Brian C. Hall's book *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations*.  In particular, see p. 96.

Comment: ah... so I was missing something obvious, in particular that for matrix groups, $\mathrm{conj}_g$ is a linear map and thus $\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}\mathrm{conj}_g(\exp tX)=\mathrm{conj}_g(\frac{d}{dt}\big|_{t=0}\exp tX)=\mathrm{conj}_g(X)$; anyway, +1

Comment: @Christoph Yeah actually I don't think it's obvious at all. When you asked that I got pretty confused for a moment; thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @joshphysics Thank you josh, I really appreciate it. So when we say 'a field, $\phi$, is in the adjoint rep of SU(2)' (as an arbitrary example), does this mean that matrices belonging to the adjoint rep of the Lie algebra (ad) are the matrices that matrix multiply the field $\phi$?

Comment: Incidentally, I was torn about who to click for the accepted answer. Both really helped me out but twistor59 got there first.

Comment: @SirajRKhan No prob.  Yeah that's right.

Comment: @joshphysics: yeah, I don't think it's actually as obvious as I thought - my argument works for matrix groups that are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, but does it work in general?

Comment: @Christoph Yea I'm not sure how generally it holds.  Hall defines a **matrix Lie group** as a *closed* subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$, and then uses the convention I use in the response for $\mathrm{Ad}$...

Comment: @joshphysics: closed under the group operation (which would be redundant, but I've heard it used before), closed as in closed manifold (ie compact and without boundary) or topologically closed ;) ; [these lecture notes](http://www.math.duke.edu/~bryant/267/LieGroupNotes.pdf) just say *Of course, this formula is valid for any matrix Lie group*, so it really might be trivial even if I don't see it yet

Comment: @Christoph Hall is referring to what essentially amounts to topologically closed using a notion of convergence that he defines earlier.

Comment: @joshphysics Sorry to return to this but I believe that my previous comment was incorrect. When we say 'a field, $\phi$ is in the adjoint rep of SU(2)' this typically means that the fields transform as $\phi \rightarrow g \phi g^{-1}$. In other words when we talk about fields and their gauge transformations in physics we take 'representions' to mean the group definition of a representation, not the Lie algebra definition. However when we say, for example, 'SU(N) has $N^{2} - 1$ generators' we actually mean the Lie algebra definition of a generator (as opposed to the generator of a group).

Comment: @SirajRKhan I added an addendum that might help in this regard.  And yeah, then physicists refer to generators in the context of Lie groups, they usually mean elements of a basis for the Lie algebra of the group.

Comment: Excellent exposition. Thanks.